# Drop only specified amount of duplicates pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Whereas panda's `drop_duplicates` function can be specified with `"first"`, `"last"`, or `False`. I want to be able to keep *N* amount of duplicates. Instead of keeping just one (e.g. with "first" or "last"), or none (with "False"), I want to keep a certain amount of the duplicates.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I suspect what you're looking for can be handled with [GroupBy.head()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html). If you want anything more specific than that, I'd need a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could work, but you haven't specified whether you are using one or more column(s) to deduplicate:

```
n = 3
df.groupby('drop_dup_col').head(n)
```

This can be used to keep the first three duplicates based on a column value from the top (head) of the dataframe. If you want to start from the bottom of the df, you can use .tail(n) instead.

Change n to the amount of rows you want to keep and change 'drop_dup_col' to the column name you are using to dedup your df.

Multiple columns can be specified in groupby using:

```
df.groupby(['col1','col5'])
```

Regarding the question in your comment:

It's a bit hard to implement, because if you want to say delete 3 duplicates there should also be a minimum of 3 duplicates, otherwise in case 2 duplicates occur they will be deleted from the data and no row is kept.

```
n = 3
df['dup_count'] = df.groupby('drop_dup_col').transform('size')
df2 = df
df2 = df2.loc[df['dup_count'] >= n]
df3 = pd.concat([df, df2])
df3.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

Comment: Thanks! Similarly, how could I go by approaching this to instead delete n duplicates, rather than keep n duplicates.

Comment: @You_Donut I edited my original answer

Answer (score 1):

I believe a combination of groupby and tail(N) should work for this-
In this case, if you want to keep 4 duplicates  in df['myColumnDuplicates']:

```
df.groupby('myColumnDuplicates').tail(4)
```

To be more precise, and complete the answer with @Stijn 's answer,
tail(n) would keep the last n duplicated values found- while head(n) should keep the first n duplicated values